# ASP.NET MVC 5 One-To-Many Create View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, one-to-many

I am a newbie with ASP.NET MVC 5 design-Pattern. Kindly look at my problem and please help me in following scenario.

Here it is my table structure:

**Order**
( Id
 | CustomerName
 | OrderDate )

**OrderDetail**
( Id
 | OrderId
 | ProductId
 | Quantity )

**Product**
( Id
 | Name )

Order can have more than one detail, mean while detail has reference to product table. I want to create a screen where user can create new order, select products and also define quantity against each product.

I was not able to get a start point for create screen of this scenario in MVC Pattern.

Thanks.

Comment: Refer the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for dynamically add items to a collection.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you very much, that's what i was exactly looking for.